# Make functional method work without instance of a class

Tags: java

**This code doesn't work:**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyConsumer<S> {
    void accept(S val);

    boolean equals(Object obj);

}

public class LambdaClass {

    public void consumerUsage(String f, MyConsumer<String> printer){
        printer.accept(f);
    }
}


public class FunctionalMethodAux {
    static List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void lambdaAux (String s){
        if (s.length() < 3) {
            System.out.println(s);
        } else {
            System.out.println(s.substring(0, 3));
        }

        stringList.add(s);
    }

    public void fmTest(){
        LambdaClass l = new LambdaClass();
        String[] words = {"trololo", "foo", "bar"};
        for(String src : words){
            l.consumerUsage(src, FunctionalMethodAux::lambdaAux); // Problematic line.
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**This code works:**

```
    String[] words = {"trololo", "foo", "bar"};
    Arrays.sort(words, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

**Question:**
If I change like this:

```
    l.consumerUsage(src, new FunctionalMethodAux()::lambdaAux)
```

everything works.

Why does `String::compareToIgnoreCase` work without new? How can I rewrite my own method for it to work without new?

(NB: `compareToIgnoreCase` is not a static method).

Comment: Can you show your `LambdaClass`?

Comment: CrystalSpider, I have edited my post.

Comment: `lambdaAux` is an instance method. It needs an instance. Did you want a static method?

Comment: user2357112, to the best of my ability I can see that  compareToIgnoreCase is also an isntance method. This is the essence of the question.

Comment: The `String::compareToIgnoreCase` in `Arrays.sort(words, String::compareToIgnoreCase);` represents `Comparator<String>`. Since Comparator expects implementation of `public int compare(String o1, String o2)` equivalent lambda could look like `(o1, o2) -> o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2)` so as you see that method has *instance* on which it will be invoked (first parameter) and that is what `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would use to call `compareToIgnoreCase` method. But now try to write lambda for `FunctionalMethodAux::lambdaAux`.

Comment: Yep, I was about to write an answer with the same content as @Pshemo 's comment.

Comment: @CrystalSpider Feel free to do so. My comment is there to show direction, it doesn't contain all info which proper answer should have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a confusion with syntax because [there are multiple types of method references in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

1. reference to static methods
2. reference to instance methods of a particular object
3. reference to instance methods of an arbitrary object of a particular type

They may look similar but have different meaning.

They have difference syntax and usage. The code with `String::compareToIgnoreCase` is an example of case #3.
Here `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)` could be triggered on 2 arbitrary String objects `a` and `b`.
The `Arrays.sort` accepts `Comparator<? super T> c` and `Comparator` is a functional interface with method which has signature `int compare(T o1, T o2)`. Since both arguments have the same `String` type and return value is `int`, it becomes possible to refer to the method with double-colon syntax.

If you have to achieve the same with your custom method `lambdaAux`.
As it is not static, option #1 is thrown out.
Option #3 is not possible because it assumes that the method is an "instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type". In your case, `lambdaAux` is an instance method of `FunctionalMethodAux` but your `consumerUsage` method expects such method to be in `String` class, hence compile error.

So if you need to use method reference, you can only go with option #2 as you have already mentioned.